# The function takes in input a list of strings x and returns an integer ptr

Tags: python, regex, string

The function takes in input a list of strings x and returns an integer ptr

 if and only if x[ptr] is a substring of at least one of the other strings in x.
 Otherwise, it returns -1. 
Can anybody help me understand this statement ?

Output should be like this.

```
def test1_exercise_7(self):
    list1 = ["goat"]
    ptr = fun_exercise_7(list1)
    self.assertTrue(ptr == -1)

def test2_exercise_7(self):
    list1 = ["soul", "soulmate", "origin"]
    ptr = fun_exercise_7(list1)
    self.assertTrue(ptr == 0)

def test3_exercise_7(self):
    list1 = ["FASER", "submission", "online", "drive", "frequent"]
    ptr = fun_exercise_7(list1)
    self.assertTrue(ptr == -1)

def test4_exercise_7(self):
    list1 = ["banana", "applejuice", "kiwi", "strawberry", "apple", "peer"]
    ptr = fun_exercise_7(list1)
    self.assertTrue(ptr == 4)
```

Comment: Have you tried writing some code yet?

Comment: I haven't because I can't understand the statement well enough  to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have to return the index of a string, which is a substring of some other string in the given list. If there is no string matches the above condition then you have to return -1

The following function will help to achieve that!

```
def fun_exercise_7(words):
    for idx,word in enumerate(words):
        matching=[idx for i,w in enumerate(words) if i!=idx if word in w]
        if matching:
            return matching[0]
        else:
            continue
    return -1
```

Comment: The OP is finding it difficult to understand the requirement of the question. Posting the solution doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I explained the requirement first and then given solution, which will make the understanding crystal clear.

Comment: Thankyou so much for solving it for me.:) 
I missed this easy statement.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

The function is given a list of strings. It's supposed to find an element in the list that's a substring of some other element of the list. It should return the index of the element containing the substring, or `-1` if there isn't one.

For instance, in the second example, `soul` is a substring of `soulmate`, so it returns `0`, the index of `soul`. In the last example, `apple` is a substring of `applejuice`, so it returns `4`, the index of `apple`. In the other two examples, none of the strings are substrings of other strings, so they return `-1`.

The description doesn't say what to do if there's more than element that satisfies the condition, e.g. in `["soul", "mate", "soulmate"]` both `soul` and `mate` are substrings of `soulmate`, and in `["soul", "ice", "soulmate", "juice"]` `soul` is a substring of `soulmate` and `ice` is a substring of `juice`. I suppose you can return the index of the first element you encounter using whatever algorithm you devise for it.

Comment: Thankyou It helped me understand the statement well. :)